# Basic bash script with sftp

Tags: bash, shell, sftp

I'm trying to make a simple bash script that invokes sftp.

When in interactive mode, whenever the user uses 'put' on a file, I want to echo out some metadata information on that file.

I'm reading the Bash Guide for Beginners on tldp.org, but it's immediately obvious to me on how to write an if statement that checks whenever the user hits the 'put' command.

Thanks.

Edit: Added some basic code and elaboration.

```
#!/bin/bash

sftp 133.43.453.132 # I made up this IP for demonstration purposes
while True
do
if [user uses 'put' to a transfer a file to remote server] # New to bash so I don't know how to express this.
    then
        echo "Random stuff"
fi
done
```

So basically, how do I write this if condition?

Comment: please show what you have so far

Comment: In general, you don't.  That is, it is difficult to use a bash script to control another command while at the same time allowing the user to interact with it.  There is a tool called [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) that can do this sort of thing, but it's non-trivial to do anything complicated with it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I want to do this because whenever the user uses put, to put a file on the server, I want put to echo out some metadata for that file. How exactly should I do this then? I'm not familiar with bash, so I don't know the optimal way to express this.

Answer (score 1):

A naive approach could be

```
#!/bin/bash
sftp 133.43.453.132 | tee /dev/tty |
while read prompt command argument1 rest
do
    case $command in put) echo "Random stuff";;
    esac
done
```

- to account for things like command line editing or output sequencing, at least a more sophisticated filter than `tee /dev/tty` would be needed.